# Creating heat map with R from a square matrix

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a gzip compressed file `file.gz` with 4,726,276 lines where the first and last five lines look like this:

```
 FID1 IID1 FID2 IID2 RT    EZ      Z0      Z1      Z2  PI_HAT PHE       DST     PPC   RATIO
 CAN  -1 CAN   1 OT     0  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  -1  0.745118  0.1111  1.5526
 CAN  -1 CAN   2 OT     0  0.8761  0.1239  0.0000  0.0619  -1  0.752607  0.0648  1.4615
 CAN  -1 CAN   3 OT     0  0.8810  0.1190  0.0000  0.0595  -1  0.753934  0.3058  1.7941
 CAN  -1 CAN   4 OT     0  0.8911  0.1089  0.0000  0.0545  -1  0.751706  0.8031  2.4138

 WAN   2 WAN   4 OT     0  0.8410  0.0000  0.1590  0.1590  -1  0.787251  0.0840  1.5000
 WAN   2 WAN   5 OT     0  0.8606  0.0000  0.1394  0.1394  -1  0.784882  0.7671  2.3571
 WAN   3 WAN   4 OT     0  0.8306  0.0000  0.1694  0.1694  -1  0.790142  0.0392  1.3846
 WAN   3 WAN   5 OT     0  0.7960  0.0364  0.1676  0.1858  -1  0.795924  0.5000  2.0000
 WAN   4 WAN   5 OT     0  0.8227  0.0090  0.1683  0.1728  -1  0.793460  0.5577  2.0645
```

The x-value is column 1 + 2. The y-value is column 3 + 4. The z-value is column 10. Values along the diagonal are not present in the input file. They should preferably be 1, but 0 is also fine.

How can I create a heat map from such data?

Here is a simple example for a 3x3 matrix:

```
FID1 IID1 FID2 IID2 PI_HAT
A 1 B 1 0.1
A 1 B 2 0.2
B 1 B 2 0.3
```

Comment: column 1 is FID1, how do you add CAN and -1?

Comment: @rawr I add them as strings. 'CAN' + '-1' = 'CAN-1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `ggplot2` approach. 4.5m rows shouldn't be a problem in R.

```
df <- read.table(text='FID1 IID1 FID2 IID2 RT    EZ      Z0      Z1      Z2  PI_HAT PHE       DST     PPC   RATIO
 CAN  -1 CAN   1 OT     0  1.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  -1  0.745118  0.1111  1.5526
 CAN  -1 CAN   2 OT     0  0.8761  0.1239  0.0000  0.0619  -1  0.752607  0.0648  1.4615
 CAN  -1 CAN   3 OT     0  0.8810  0.1190  0.0000  0.0595  -1  0.753934  0.3058  1.7941
 CAN  -1 CAN   4 OT     0  0.8911  0.1089  0.0000  0.0545  -1  0.751706  0.8031  2.4138
 CAN  -1 CAN   4 OT     0  0.8911  0.1089  0.0000  0.0545  -1  0.751706  0.8031  2.4138
 CAN  -1 CAN   4 OT     0  0.8911  0.1089  0.0000  0.0545  -1  0.751706  0.8031  2.4138
 WAN   3 WAN   4 OT     0  0.8306  0.0000  0.1694  0.1694  -1  0.790142  0.0392  1.3846
 WAN   3 WAN   4 OT     0  0.8306  0.0000  0.1694  0.1694  -1  0.790142  0.0392  1.3846
 WAN   2 WAN   4 OT     0  0.8410  0.0000  0.1590  0.1590  -1  0.787251  0.0840  1.5000
 WAN   2 WAN   5 OT     0  0.8606  0.0000  0.1394  0.1394  -1  0.784882  0.7671  2.3571
 WAN   3 WAN   4 OT     0  0.8306  0.0000  0.1694  0.1694  -1  0.790142  0.0392  1.3846
 WAN   3 WAN   5 OT     0  0.7960  0.0364  0.1676  0.1858  -1  0.795924  0.5000  2.0000
 WAN   4 WAN   5 OT     0  0.8227  0.0090  0.1683  0.1728  -1  0.793460  0.5577  2.0645', header=T)
```

I added a few lines in your output to make it more reasonable in a heatmap. There was no overlap previously:

```
#create your variables by merging columns 1+2 and 3+4
a <- mapply(paste,df[[1]], df[[2]])
b <- mapply(paste,df[[3]], df[[4]])
#combine in a data.frame
df2 <- data.frame(a,b)


library(dplyr)
#aggregate because you will need aggregated rows for this to work
#this should only take a few seconds for 4.5m rows
df3 <-
df2 %>%
  group_by(a,b) %>%
  summarize(total=n())

#plot with ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df3, aes(x=a,y=b,fill=total)) + geom_tile()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't usually use R. Where do you define the variable df?

Comment: 4.5 Million rows would be a problem in R, but fortunately he didn't mean that his data has 4.5 million rows.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen first line of my code. the read.table function assigns your data into variable `df`. In R you do not define variables explicitly.

Comment: @Hack-R Hi Hack. I meant it is not gonna be a problem for doing aggregations or data manipulation. As long as he uses C++ implemented functions like the above it will be fine. Plotting a few thousand rows matrix won't be a problem either I think :)

Comment: Thanks. I just need to install the module/package/library dplyr.

Comment: `dplyr` and `ggplot2` for plotting and you should be fine! Really glad I could be of help and if you need any more explanation for this one let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to have 2 parts:

1. How to handle the data in R (in this case coming from a gzip compressed archive)
2. How to make a heatmap

At first blush, it appeared that you were implying that the size of the data was large -- there are many resources on how to use Big Data in R ([here's one](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/09/03/handling-big-data-in-r/)) -- however based on the comments I take it that the data size is actually not an issue. If it were then your options would depend in part on your hardware resources as well as your willingness to sample data (which I highly recommend) rather than use every single one of your 5 million rows. 
The [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) is your friend.

You can read in `gzip` data like this:

```
data <- read.table(gzfile("file.gz"),header=T, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Since you did not provide your compressed archive, I've copied your sample data and read it from my clipboard in the code below. I'll show you how to construct a heatmap from this data; for importing from gzip and handling Big Data check out the link provided above.

```
require(stats)
require(fields)
require(akima)

a <- read.table(con <- file("clipboard"), header = T)

a$x1 <- as.numeric(a[,1])
a$x2 <- as.numeric(a[,2])
a$y1 <- as.numeric(a[,3])
a$y2 <- as.numeric(a[,4])
x <- as.matrix(cbind(a$x1, a$x2))
y <- as.matrix(cbind(a$y1, a$y2))
z <- as.matrix(a[, 10])

s = smooth.2d(z, x=cbind(x,y), theta=0.5)
image.plot(s)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is however not big data. The file only has a few million lines and the matrix hence only a few thousand rows and columns.

Comment: Your use of the term "lines" as opposed to "rows" is a little unclear, but if the data is not big then it should be all the easier, no?

Comment: By lines I mean lines in the input file. By rows I mean rows in the matrix and the heat map. I don't usually use R (I do gnuplot and matplotlib), so it's not easy for me.

Comment: OK so read in the gzip data like this: `data <- read.table(gzfile("file.gz"),header=T, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=F)`. If you provide the zipped file I can show you how to do it with your data.

Comment: I have provided a simple example for a 3x3 matrix. I edited the question.